# is there a way to shorten this expression?

Tags: php

```
$titleadd = substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
$titleadd = str_replace('.php', '', $titleadd);
$titleadd = str_replace('-', ' ', $titleadd);
```

I'm getting the url, removing the http://www.domain.com/ then replacing the .php and any hyphens in the url to echo out the page name.

So **www.google.com/my-page.php** would output as **my page**

Is there a shorter way of doing this?

Comment: Does this actually work? That code makes no sense.

Comment: str_replace can take from and to arrays

Comment: It works great! I just echo out $titleadd at the end of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shorter equivalent for your use case is

```
$titleadd = strtr(basename($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], ".php"), "-", " ");
```

Of course this is not industrial-grade parsing, but it should give as good a result as your original code.

A more robust attempt would involve [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), but it will hardly end up being shorter than what you have there. On the other hand: perhaps code length is not the correct metric here? After all, you can hide 200 lines of code behind `foo()` and noone will ever know.

Comment: That's a great shorter version! Thank you :) I'm not looking to hide code. I just wanted something a little shorter than I had. What do you mean by not "industrial-grade"?

Would it be possible to caps each word, eg change **my site** to **My Site**

Comment: @GT22: [`ucwords`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) will do that as long as you are only handling latin letters. By "industrial-grade" I mean that the code above may not work correctly if the input changes even a little bit (depending on the change).

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace('-', ' ', basename('www.google.com/my-page.php', '.php'));
```